# How to observe Firebase Storage object's downloadUrl change?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Let's say we store user's photo in Storage and in users 'photoURL' we store that image's downloadUrl.

After, let's say somehow that photo's downloadUrl is revoked somehow, by the admin of the app or some other reason.

Now, user's photoURL is gone.

Is there any way to observe storage items' dowloadUrl changes? I couldn't find yet. If there is not; here are 2 ideas; which one I should go for?

#### Second way:

Store storage location instead of downloadURL and request dowloadUrl everytime, which I don't want to do since it requires total of 3 requests, instead 2. This should be too much for social media-like app. Also, if the user authenticated via Facebook, Twitter etc, their photo will be served by these providers, and I will need to check every url if it is a "storage location" or a direct url.

#### Third way:

Use gravatar or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Revoking download URLs is fairly uncommon, although possible. A more common situation is that a new image is uploaded at the same path in storage, that image gets a new download URL. There is no built-in API in the Firebase Storage API to observe these changes.

The common approach is to store the download URLs into another place that **is** observable, and update it whenever the image changes (together with other metadata about the image). Typically you'll use Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore for this. In there you store the download URL as a property/field of the node/document it belong to. Then by using a realtime observer, you can detect changes to the download URL.

Comment: Yes, the approach is similar what I do for my posts. I'm holding dowloadURL as well as the storage location in Firestore (and meta's that I need). First, I use the downloadURL to get the image, if it fails, I request a new downloadURL from storage location and update the old downloadURL. But I cannot do that for users photoURL since it is not a place for mappings or arrays

Comment: One other approach came to my mind is instead of requesting downloadURL, directly requesting the data. But I do not know if it affects performace etc.

Comment: If you store the download URL in a database, you should update that data when the download URL gets updates, so from the code that uploads the new image, or when you revoke the existing download URL.

Comment: I'm handling all possible actions that I can catch with triggers in cloud functions. But just in case still holding the storage location. Also this was my question. You say **or when you revoke the existing download URL** and looks like revoking is not catchable by any triggers.

Comment: That's correct. Since token revocation doesn't affect the stored object, there's no trigger for it. If you programmatically revoke the token, you can trigger a HTTPS function once the revoke call returns.

Comment: And in the end, I have no solution in my terms. OK then, will use storage location to not risk it. If it becomes a headache, I can write a script to change them whatever I want. Thanks your time and concern!